# Can I replace the end connection of a never-kink hose with interior ribs?

Tags: repair, hose

We have a 'never-kink' garden hose, one end of which had an unfortunate interaction with a mower.  The inside walls of the hose has fairly prominent plastic(?) ribs.  (Presumably, the anti-kink device.)  ISTM that those ribs would prevent an ordinary repair fitting from sealing inside the hose.

Is such a hose repairable?   [image]

Answer (score 6):

Might as well try it. It works, (they squish enough to let it seal) or it doesn't, and if it doesn't, you put the repair fitting away until the next hose incident.

I suppose if you wanted to fool with such things you could add some silicone rubber caulking to the fitting before shoving it in, and wait a day or two for that to cure before clamping it. That might fill the spaces between the ribs adequately.

Comment: Or you use a rasp bit on a drill (or similar) to smooth out the ID for the depth of the barb on the repair fitting.

Comment: That would be difficult to manage, practically speaking, in a flexible hose.

Comment: @Ecnwewal how so?  You can buy a 5/8" diameter rasp.  Only need to smooth out an inch or two.  Easy peasy.